# How can one keg be overcarbonated on a 4-line setup when all the other beers pour just fine?

Tags: carbonation, kegerator, corny-keg, foam, over-carbonation

A while ago I purchased a 4-line kegerator, I have one CO2 tank that carbonates 4 kegs of beer at around 11 psi. When I bring a new uncarbonated keg online, I just add it to an empty gas line and let it carbonate slowly over the course of one week (no force carbonation at 30 psi or rolling the keg around).

About one week ago I added a brand new uncarbonated keg (Pale Ale) and I was expecting it to 
be carbonated today. I tried to pour my first pint and all of a sudden a lot of foam came out and it seemed to pour at a much higher pressure than my other beers. I tried to pour several more beers, but they all had the same foaming issue.

I took the keg offline, released the pressure and opened the lid and saw a lot of foam inside the keg as well.

It puzzles me how this could have happened since I have 4 beers on the same setup and none of the other kegs have a foaming issue. My regulator is still showing 11 psi. And I don't believe that there is anything wrong with the beer since I bottled another keg with my neighbor and it pours perfectly on his kegerator.

Any ideas what could have happened?

Comment: do you know if either yours or your friend's setup includes a check valve?

Comment: Was the beer fully fermented when you kegged it?

Comment: What temperature was the new keg at before you added it? Beer tends to absorb more CO2 as it cools.

Comment: @mdma no check valve inline, not sure if there is one at the regulator, but I doubt it

Comment: @Robert Yes, the beer was fully fermented, checked it with Hydrometer

Comment: @jalynn2 The keg was at room temperature when I hooked it up and put it in the kegerator, but I have done it for all the prior kegs the same way and never had an issue

Comment: Another thing to check would be the possibility of a clog in the line out.

Comment: @DHough I've had clogs actually in the picnic tap itself. The lines may look clean, but check the tap!

Comment: Did that as well, tried multiple taps, always the same result

Answer (score 2):

Could be any number of things.

Style of beer, some styles require more/less carbonation and pressure. Could be a kink or something in the line that causes the beer to bubble/foam in the line on the way out.

Maybe try hooking the keg up to one of your other faucets?

Comment: Switching connections is exactly what I was thinking. Why wonder?

Answer (score 1):

I've had that happen with an infection before. Check valve keeps the pressure from heading to the other kegs, but it builds up in the infected keg.

Comment: My keg does not seem to be infected, beer tastes perfectly fine